# Some websites know my nationality (spooky)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, regional-settings

Websites can tell what country you are from, nothing unusual about this. But several years ago I moved to the US and bought a new desktop computer (built it myself from parts I bought from amazon, all us based vendors). The rationality of the operating system was US American English.

But some websites (not very often, http://waifu2x.udp.jp/ is the primary example I can think of, unfortunately the website is down) still appear in my native language. This is very very odd to me. My google account is set up as english as well. It doesnt matter which browser I use. Incognito mode/private mode does not matter.

How would a website know this?

Comment: `.jp` means Japan, right? Is your native language Japanese? Maybe the site would appear in Japanese for *anyone*. I'm Polish and `.pl` sites appear in Polish not because they know me but because their content is Polish.

Comment: nope, im not japanese. this website has (had) many different language versions.